# Raw SQL queries in Django views

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-views

How would I perform the following using raw SQL in `views.py`?

```py
from app.models import Picture

def results(request):
    all = Picture.objects.all()
    yes = Picture.objects.filter(vote='yes').count()
    return render_to_response(
        'results.html', 
        {'picture':picture, 'all':all, 'yes': yes}, 
        context_instance=RequestContext(request)
    )
```

What would this `results` function look like?

Comment: Why would you want to use raw sql for that query over filtering and count?

Comment: No practical reason for this case. Just to see/know how to do it.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

```
>>> from django.db import connection
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> cursor.execute('''SELECT count(*) FROM people_person''')
1L
>>> row = cursor.fetchone()
>>> print row
(12L,)
>>> Person.objects.all().count()
12
```

use WHERE clause to filter vote for yes:

```
>>> cursor.execute('''SELECT count(*) FROM people_person WHERE vote = "yes"''')
1L
```

Comment: Very useful! Thanks! I used `rows = cursor.fetchall()`.

Answer (score 81):

[The Django Documentation is really really good.](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) You have basically two options to execute raw SQL. You can use `Manager.raw()` to perform raw queries which return model instances, or you can avoid the model layer and execute custom SQL directly.

Using the `raw()` manager:

```
>>> for p in Person.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_person'):
...     print p
John Smith
Jane Jones
```

If you want to bypass the model layer directly you can use `django.db.connection` which represents the default database connection:

```
def my_custom_sql():
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    # Data modifying operation - commit required
    cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    transaction.commit_unless_managed()

    # Data retrieval operation - no commit required
    cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
    row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

Comment: +1 nice explanation, would you be able to return a count using raw?

Comment: No, it returns a `RawQuerySet` which is only useful if you want to return a model instance. To perform `count(*)` or anything else where you don't want to return a model instance you are better off just using `django.db.connection`.

Comment: disagree about the django docs

Answer (score 12):

It can be done within one query if you are using PostgreSQL.
If not, you can change the query accordingly and get the results.

```
from django.db import connection

def results(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        query = """
        SELECT count(*) as all_count, 
        count(*) FILTER(WHERE vote = 'yes') as yes_count
        FROM people_person;
        """
        cursor.execute(query)
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        all_count, yes_count = row
```

Answer (score 9):

**Raw sql with the specific database name:**

```
from django.db import connections
cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
cursor.execute("select * from table_name")
print(cursor.fetchall())

# manually close the cursor if you are done!
cursor.close()
```

```
database_name = Any database created by us
table_name = Any table name created by us
```

Answer (score 6):

You Can try this

```
Picture.objects.raw("SELECT 1 as id ,"\
 "(SELECT  count(*) as yes FROM people_person WHERE vote='yes') as yes ,"\
 "(SELECT  count(*) FROM people_person WHERE vote='no') as no ,"\
 "(SELECT  count(*) FROM people_person WHERE vote='all') as all ")
```

Comment: this is a fragile trick, as it will work only with integer primary keys (not uuid for example)

Comment: When I used this way of running raw SQL, I got NameError: name 'MyModel' is not defined. How do you run it under the context of django ORM?

Answer (score 4):

**raw()** method can be used to perform raw sql queries that return model instances ..[see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-queries)

```
books = Book.objects.raw('SELECT id,name,pages FROM app_books WHERE pages>100')
```

if you might perform queries that don't map cleanly to models ..
django.db.connection represents default database connection so call
**connection.cursor()** to use database connection. [see docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)

```
from django.db import connection
def my_custom_sql(self):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
        cursor.execute("SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
        row = cursor.fetchone()

    return row
```

Answer (score 2):

For example, you have **`Person` model** as shown below:

```py
# "store/models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

Then, you can run **the raw SQL query** with `cursor.execute()` and get the result with `cursor.fetchall()` and if there is no more result, `cursor.fetchall()` returns `[]` as shown below. *[**The documentation**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) explains more about it:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM store_person;") # Here

        for row in cursor.fetchall(): # Here
            print(row)

        print(cursor.fetchall()) # []

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Output on console:

```
(1, 'Tom')
(2, 'David')
(3, 'Lisa')
[]
```

And, you can also use `cursor.fetchone()` to get the result and if there is no more result, `cursor.fetchone()` returns `None` as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM store_person;") # Here

        print(cursor.fetchone()) # (1, 'Tom')
        print(cursor.fetchone()) # (2, 'David')
        print(cursor.fetchone()) # (3, 'Lisa')
        print(cursor.fetchone()) # None

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Output on console:

```
(1, 'Tom')
(2, 'David')
(3, 'Lisa')
None
```

And, you can also use **transaction** as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse

@transaction.atomic # Here
def test(request):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM store_person;''')

        for row in cursor.fetchall():
            print(row)

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Or:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from django.db import transaction
from django.db import connection
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):
    with transaction.atomic(): # Here
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute('''SELECT * FROM store_person;''')

            for row in cursor.fetchall():
                print(row)

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Or:

```py
DATABASES = {
    'default':{
        'ENGINE':'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME':'postgres',
        'USER':'postgres',
        'PASSWORD':'admin',
        'HOST':'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
        'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': True, # Here
    },
}
```

Then, transaction is run according to these PostgreSQL logs below. *I used **PostgreSQL** and [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54780698/postgresql-database-log-transaction/73432601#73432601) explains how to log PostgreSQL queries:

```
[21200] LOG:  duration: 0.008 ms  statement: BEGIN
[21200] LOG:  duration: 1.232 ms  statement: SELECT * FROM store_person;
[21200] LOG:  duration: 0.024 ms  statement: COMMIT
```