# Raw queries and custom sql queries what is the fastest?

Tags: python, sql, django

Assuming that the file **models.py** in my [django](/questions/tagged/django) application (webapp) is like the following :

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import connection

class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    surname = models.CharField(...)

def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Returns all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    desc = cursor.description
    return [
        dict(zip([col[0] for col in desc], row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]

def get_foo():
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM foo_table')
    rows = dictfetchall(cursor)
    return rows
```

To get access to my **database content**, I have basicly two options :

### Option 1 :

```
from webapp.models import Foo
bar = Foo.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM foo_table')
```

### Option 2 :

```
from application.models import get_foo
bar = get_foo()
```

Which option is the fastest in execution ? 
Is there a better way to do what I want to do ?

Comment: Why use Django if you are not going to take advantage of the nice abstractions? Beyond that, does it need to be the fastest possible? Do it the most readable, maintainable way, then, if you find you desperately need performance, optimise the bottlenecks.

Comment: Also, trying to dump the results of a `SELECT *` in to a dictionary (in memory) is probably not advisable.

Comment: What is wrong with using `Foo.objects.all()` if you want to just select every record? Have a look at the QuerySet API - most use cases can be solved with it.

Comment: Django essentially does "SELECT `list all foo_table cols here` FROM foo_table" which is as fast. It might take a few ops to generate the list of cols, but its no biggie. It does protect you to use explicit table cols though as any DBA would tell you. The protection comes from being explicit, so that even if the table structure changes for any reason in the future your code is safer.

Comment: Raw SQL is always faster. In any ORM vs RAW raw always wins just because the what the ORM brings to the table is the easiness and abstractions but then takes a part of performance as boon.

Comment: you can get the query that django would generate, and time the raw v/s orm query to see what fares better

Comment: @sr2222 In fact I am using more complexe requests like `SELECT count(*) FROM Question inner join Ask on question_id=question_ask WHERE quiz_ask = %s`

Comment: @Lattyware I will follow your advice, the most readable, the better.

Comment: Also, unless you are running against a local database (and probably even then), the impact of stripping off ORM layers is going to be minimal compared to the network latency.  You should probably look at optimizing your models and schema before trying to strip out the ORM layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct and clear answer on which approach is better.

Using `Manager.raw()` still keeps you within the `ORM` layer and while it returns Model instances you still have a nice database abstraction. But, while making a raw query, django does more than just `cursor.execute` in order to translate the results into Model instances (see what is happening in [RawQuerySet](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L1435) and [RawQuery](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/sql/query.py#L34) classes).

But (quote from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)):

> Sometimes even Manager.raw() isn’t quite enough: you might need to
>   perform queries that don’t map cleanly to models, or directly execute
>   UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE queries.

So, generally speaking, what to choose depends on what results are going to get and what you are going to do with them.

See also:

- [Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/)
- [executing-custom-sql-directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)
- [Raw sql queries in Django views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931586/raw-sql-queries-in-django-views)

Comment: You are right, django makes more than a `cursor.execute` when using `Foo.objects.raw()`, so I have my answer. I prefer using cursors to interract with my database, because there is some things that I don't know how to do in python and that are very easy with SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Using the connection cursor is for sure the faster than using `raw()` as it doesn't instantiate additionals objects... But for really telling what the fastest solution is you should do some benchmarking!

And don't overdo optimizations if not necessary because you are avoiding some of Django's most useful features this way as long as you don't have any serious performance problems. And if you have some they will most likely not be the result of how you execute the query. Of course you will be able to write better queries if you exactly know your use case and the ORM doesn't.