# how to retrive values form RawQuerySet in django?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

**my input query is**

```
query = "select * from tab1 left join tab2 on tab2.patient_id =tab1.patient_id ,tab3 left join tab4 on tab4.patient_id =tab3.patient_id"

data = model_name.objects.raw(query)
```

How do you retrieve values from a `RawQuerySet`?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931586/raw-sql-queries-in-django-views

Answer (score 11):

The result obtained by making raw queries using `raw` method of `Manager` generates instances similar to instances generated using `get` or `filter` method. To get a field simply do `obj_name.attr`.
For eg:

```
class Tab(models.Model):
    field1 = models.BooleanField()
    field2 = models.PositiveIntegerField()

query = "select * from app_name_tab"
objs = Tab.objects.raw(query)
for obj in objs:
    print obj.field1, obj.field2
```

For more info, refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

Comment: thank for your reply.. 

i want to access all fields data. i don't know column name since join query generating dynamically...

Comment: You could use `tab._meta.fields` to get the list of all fields in the table. Iterate over them and use `getattr` method get values like this: `for f in obj._meta.fields: print getattr(obj, f)`

Comment: I had a RawQuerySet object and needed to know how to retrieve values of attributes contained as collections within the object. This answer is exactly what I needed. I don't understand why it had been down-voted in the first place.