# Is there a Django function for converting RawQuerySet to dataframe

Tags: django

I need to run a query like this - 
historic_data.objects.raw("select * from company_historic_data")

This return a RawQuerySet. I have to convert values from this to a dataframe. the usual .values() method does not work with raw query. Can someone suggest a solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to retrive values form RawQuerySet in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20325168/how-to-retrive-values-form-rawqueryset-in-django)

Answer (score 4):

Try the codes below

```
import pandas as pd

res = model.objects.raw('select * from some_table;')
df = pd.DataFrame([item.__dict__ for item in res])
```

Note that there is a `_state` column in the returned dataframe