# Django Making query Raw SQL

Tags: python, django

model

```
class Member(models.Model):
   id_unit = models.ForeignKey(Unit)
   id_fleet = models.ForeignKey(Fleet)

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id_fleet)
```

views.py

```
    def fleet_member_view(request):
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select fleet_member.id_fleet_id, array_to_string(array_agg(fleet_member.id_unit_id),',') as id_unit 
            from fleet_member, setup_unit 
            where fleet_member.id_unit_id = setup_unit.id group by fleet_member.id_fleet_id")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        return render(request,'fleet_member_view.html',{'row': row}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

i want to show data in my template

```
{% for post in row %}
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
       <td>{{ post.id_fleet }}</td>
       <td>{{ post.id_unit }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

but data cannot show anything, i try query SQL in command line data show well. why data cannot show in template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cursor.fetchone()` retrieves the next row of a query result set and returns a single sequence, or `None`.

```
{% ifnotequal row None %}
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
       <td>{{ row.0 }}</td>
       <td>{{ row.1 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endifnotequal %}
```

You want to list all results, you should use `cursor.fetchall()`

View

```
def fleet_member_view(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select fleet_member.id_fleet_id, array_to_string(array_agg(fleet_member.id_unit_id),',') as id_unit 
        from fleet_member, setup_unit 
        where fleet_member.id_unit_id = setup_unit.id group by fleet_member.id_fleet_id")
    row = cursor.fetchall()
    return render(request,'fleet_member_view.html',{'row': row}, context_instance= RequestContext(request))
```

Template

```
{% for post in row %}
    <tr class="odd gradeX">
       <td>{{ post.0 }}</td>
       <td>{{ post.1 }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks for answer. but i am getting error Invalid block tag: 'endfor', expected 'else' or 'endifnotequal'

Comment: Because you are useing `cursor.fetchone()`

Comment: so how to fix it? before i use Class.objects.raw("Select query") but i am getting error 'Manager' object has no attribute 'row'. So i use this tutorial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931586/raw-sql-queries-in-django-views

Comment: thanks i try in python manage.py shell its worked. but in my template not show

Comment: i edit {{ post.0 }} and {{ post.1 }} its worked. thanks