# How to get the field value from django orm

Tags: django

I am trying to get the field value of a joined table.  This is the generated sql of ORM query.

> `SELECT`subnets_subnetoption`.`id`,`
>   subnets_subnetoption`.`subnet_id`,`subnets_subnetoption`.`value_id`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`id`,`subnets_subnet`.`parent_id`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`base_address`,`subnets_subnet`.`bits`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`bcast_address`,`subnets_subnet`.`is_physical`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`name`,`subnets_subnet`.`responsible`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`building_floor`,`subnets_subnet`.`comments`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`vlan_common_name`,`subnets_subnet`.`creation_date`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`modification_date`,`subnets_subnet`.`sec_level`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`confid`,`subnets_subnet`.`access_type`,`
>   subnets_subnet`.`zone_type`,`options_value`.`id`,`
>   options_value`.`content`,`options_value`.`comment`,`
>   options_value`.`option_id`,`options_option`.`id`,`
>   options_option`.`name`,`options_option`.`required`,`
>   options_option`.`scope_id`,`options_scope`.`id`,`
>   options_scope`.`name`FROM`subnets_subnetoption`INNER JOIN`
>   subnets_subnet`ON (`subnets_subnetoption`.`subnet_id`=`
>   subnets_subnet`.`id`) INNER JOIN`options_value`ON
>   (`subnets_subnetoption`.`value_id`=`options_value`.`id`) INNER JOIN`
>   options_option`ON (`options_value`.`option_id`=`
>   options_option`.`id`) INNER JOIN`options_scope`ON
>   (`options_option`.`scope_id`=`options_scope`.`id`) WHERE`
>   subnets_subnetoption`.`subnet_id` = 1

```
   SubnetOption.objects.select_related().filter(subnet_id=subnet['id']).query
```

I need only options_value.content and options_option.name, but query set i giving the subnetoption table values only. How can I get the joined tables values. I am new to django

Answer (score 1):

```
 SubnetOption.objects.filter(subnet_id=subnet['id']).select_related().values('options_value__content')
```

or

```
SubnetOption.objects.filter(subnet_id=subnet['id']).select_related('modelname_in_wholelowercase')
```

try this once

Comment: the entire query got changed SELECT `options_value`.`content` FROM `subnets_subnetoption` INNER JOIN `options_value` ON (`subnets_subnetoption`.`value_id` = `options_value`.`id`) WHERE `subnets_subnetoption`.`subnet_id` = 1

Comment: second one is also not working . entire join relation is removed

Answer (score 0):

You can use **raw query** of django, which means you can put SQL query as it is, for reference

[Raw sql queries in Django views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931586/raw-sql-queries-in-django-views)

Comment: as putting join is easy in sql query @Anish