# "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed."

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

here i tried with custom user login in djangorestfulapi  but i am getting error that  "detail": "Method \"POST\" not allowed." . can anybody please explain where i am getting wrong?

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    def user_login(self,request,format=None):
        # context = RequestContext(request)
        if request.method == 'POST':
            user = ''' SELECT * FROM users '''
            # Gather the username and password provided by the user.

            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            print("auth",str(authenticate(username=username, password=password)))

            if user:
                # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("xxx")
        else:
            # Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
            print ("Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password))
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")
```

endpoint url:

```
path('api/login/',LoginAPIView.as_view(), name='login'),
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [405 POST method not allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22983222/405-post-method-not-allowed)

Comment: no, it's not. @Hedgy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class based views, you should define separate method for separate http methods like this

```
class LoginAPIView(APIView):
    def post(self,request,format=None):
        user = ''' SELECT * FROM users '''
            # Gather the username and password provided by the user.

        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print("auth",str(authenticate(username=username, password=password)))

        if user:
            # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
            if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("xxx")
```

Comment: thanks man. but now i am getting error that MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/login/
'username'

Comment: This is because you have not send `username` and `password` in your post request.

Comment: i didn't get understood.

Comment: You are getting error at `username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')` part of code which clearly show that `request.POST` do not have that required data. You should send that data to your view.

Comment: @Psynora _now i am getting error that MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/login/ 'username'_ That sounds like a different issue entirely.

Comment: hi man first of all thank you so much. i have an another question please take a look at this [link](https://pastebin.com/iCaGyq8s). hope you can find a solution of it.

Comment: can you please demonstrate the issue? @AMC

Comment: @Psynora _can you please demonstrate the issue?_ Demonstrate what?

Comment: "now i am getting error that MultiValueDictKeyError at /api/login/ 'username' That sounds like a different issue entirely" could you demonstrate what kind of different issue? @AMC

Comment: How you are testing this view?

Comment: @MuhammadHassan can you please solve another problem? take a look this [link](https://pastebin.com/iCaGyq8s)

Comment: whats the problem?

Comment: Where are your models?

Comment: ofcourse i do not have any model cause i am using raw query instead of ORM. i am directly fetching data from databases. @MuhammadHassan

Comment: anyways did you find any solution?

Comment: Its better you use ORM. Its will make your task a lot easier.

Comment: i know, do you have any solution for this problem?

Comment: ORM is the solution IMO. If you want to use raw queries, use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931586/raw-sql-queries-in-django-views)