# Pythonanywhere: how to run slq script for db sqlite?

Tags: sql, django, pythonanywhere

I have deployed a Django project on Pythonanywhere.

I have a db.Sqlite3 database and I need to initiailze this database with a sql script.

I could not find how to do this in pythonanywhere and did not find any help on forums.

Is it possible (I think it is...) ?

Comment: take a look at this link  [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931586/raw-sql-queries-in-django-views ]. I think it is what you want.

Comment: You can run your script from the bash console on PythonAnywhere.