# Is there a way to create tables/entities on the Django db using RAW SQL

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, rawsql

I would like to know whether it is possible to create and setup my entities in my database(db) using RAW SQL in my Django Project.
I understand that we can use SQL Queries to handle entities that have already been created using ORM. Examples were shown in the [Django Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/sql/#:%7E:text=Django%20gives%20you%20two%20ways,ORM%20before%20using%20raw%20SQL!)

I know that using RAW SQL is inefficient compared to using Django's ORM but one of the requirements of my project is to use SQL Statements for all database related functions.

The following is the code written in models.py in my Django app:

```
class Link(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    clicks = models.PositiveBigIntegerField(default=0)
```

The following is an example of the SQL Statements needed to create my entity:

```
CREATE TABLE Link (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    url VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    slug VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
    clicks BIGINT DEFAULT 0
);
```

I can't seem to find any resources or any way to add my SQL Statements to my code using the `Manager.raw(raw_query, params=(), translations=None)` method.

Comment: It has to be ```Manager.objects.raw```, not ```Manager.raw```. See example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/sql/).

Comment: Thank you for spotting the mistake in my question but either way, I still can't create entities without the build-in ORM, I want a way with SQL Statements

Comment: You also have **cursor** option - see the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5931586/raw-sql-queries-in-django-views). You import ```from django.db import connection``` then ```cursor = connection.cursor()```.

Comment: Will that work, I heard that causes migration problems for your Django apps

Comment: You can add a new custom method to your model which will **not** be decorated as ```@property``` and run it without any impact on migrations, only if and when you need it.

Comment: Raw SQL is inefficient? Not really. Insecure? Maybe if not done properly. In general raw SQL would definitely be more efficient than using an ORM simply because some of the intermediate steps can be skipped.

Comment: Generally if you want to avoid the ORM for creating your tables, you might as well simply have those tables created outside of Django and use them with it, see the duplicate. If you do want to leverage the migration system to atleast setup your tables I've added another duplicate as well.